# Inputbinding in Style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, styles

I have a Style that should have a MouseBinding as a InputBinding that executes a Command in my ViewModel.

To do this I am using an AttachedProperty:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InputBindingsProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("InputBindings", typeof(InputBindingCollection),
    typeof(InputBindingAttached), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new InputBindingCollection(),
    (s, e) =>
    {
        UIElement element = s as UIElement;
        if (element == null || !(e.NewValue is InputBindingCollection))
            return;

        element.InputBindings.Clear();
        element.InputBindings.AddRange(e.NewValue as InputBindingCollection);
    }));

public static void SetInputBindings(UIElement element, InputBindingCollection inputbindings)
{
    element.SetValue(InputBindingsProperty, inputbindings);
}

public static InputBindingCollection GetInputBindings(UIElement element)
{
    return (InputBindingCollection)element.GetValue(InputBindingsProperty);
}
```

And this is my XAML:

```
<dc:ColumnDefinition Header="Mapper" BindingMemberPath="Mapper" Width="*">
    <dc:ColumnDefinition.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type dc:AdvGridCell}">
            <Setter Property="Attached:InputBindingAttached.InputBindings">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <InputBindingCollection>
                        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" 
                                      Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.EditMapperCommand, ElementName=parent}"/>
                    </InputBindingCollection>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </dc:ColumnDefinition.CellStyle>
</dc:ColumnDefinition>
```

My Root element in the XAML is a custom class derived from UserControl. The name of the rootelement is

```
parent
```

. In a previous project I also used exactly this and everything worked fine. But now I have a strange Error that a paramter named "Value is null". If I set a Breakpoint in the AttachdProperty I can see that it contains the Command and exactly 2 Times the AttachedProperty is set. After that I have no Stacktrace no Innerexception nothing ... just the message that any value is null.

If I use RelativeSource in Binding there is no error but the the Command is not found. I really dont know what is wrong.

Comment: One thing: NEVER do that "new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new InputBindingCollection()", unless of course you want to reuse the collection. All your controls using the attached property will use the EXACT same instasnce of the InputBindingCollection. WPF will create it once and reuse it always.

Comment: ok still same problem...